# Can a script loaded from example.com/script.js, make fetch request to example.com and not get CORS prevention error?

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

If my website origin is `notexample.com`, and If I load library from `example.com/script.js`, can this script make fetch request to `example.com` and not get CORS prevention error?

I attempted to make the request, but I was met with a CORS error. I am quite curious as to how Google went about implementing its API. With Google Maps, for example, you are unable to directly request an API endpoint or else you will receive a CORS error. However, if you use Google Maps client library that is loaded from Google servers/domain, you are able to make the request successfully. It's an interesting security measure that Google has taken, and it's something that I'd like to take some time to research further.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the script (`https://example.com`) is irrelevant, because [cross-origin script embedding is always allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access):

> Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded cross-origin:
>
> - JavaScript with `<script src="…"></script>`. [...]

What matters is the [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) in which that script is loaded. If you load that script in the context of `https://notexample.com` and the script sends a (cross-origin) request to `https://example.com`, the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will kick in.

And unless `https://example.com` is configured for CORS to allow requests from `https://notexample.com`, things will not work as expected.