# Nodejs Express api cors error on calling api using angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

i created api using nodejs express mongodb and its giving cors error when i call api from angular application.
i deployed this api on render then its working but gives an error on local

**Error**
Access to XMLHttpRequest at **'localhost:3000/api/auth/login'** from origin **'http://localhost:4200'** **has been blocked by CORS policy**: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, isolated-app, brave, https, chrome-untrusted, data, chrome-extension, chrome.
auth.service.ts:38     POST localhost:3000/api/auth/login net::ERR_FAILED
schedu

i have installed cors and added
`app.use(cors({origin : "*"}))`

or

`app.use(cors({origin : "http://localhost:4200/"}))`

but it still giving error,

also i tried adding this

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        next();
    }
```

still cors error.

here is my **index.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const dotEnv = require("dotenv");
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const cors = require("cors");

    app.use(cors({origin: "*"}));

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        next();
    }


    dotEnv.config();

    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    app.use(express.json());

    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URL).then(function(){
        console.log("connected");

    });

    


    applications = require("./routes/applications"),
    auth = require("./routes/auth"),


    



    app.use("/api/aplications", applications);
    app.use("/api/auth/", auth);





    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.listen(PORT, function(){
        console.log(Date.now())
        console.log("server started on port", PORT);
    })
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75386507/can-a-script-loaded-from-example-com-script-js-make-fetch-request-to-example-co/75386704#75386704

Comment: Either use Express.js's CORS middleware and configure it properly (better), _or_ manually set CORS headers (not great), but do _not_ do _both_.

Comment: _still cors error_. What is the error message? Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: i made mistake i forgot to add http:// while calling api, 
i added http:// and its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution i forgot to add http:// , its working now

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',  { email: email, password:password })
  .subscribe((data:any) => {
    // console.log();
    this.setToken(data.token)
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [cors npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)
i think you need to call `cors()` with empty parameter like this :

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: i made mistake i forgot to add http:// while calling api
i added http:// now its working