# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error When sending ajax request reactjs and php

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, cors

I have built a very simple React website, however I am trying to put in a PHP backend.

I followed this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-reactjs-as-a-front-end-with-php-as-a-back-end/

I keep getting a console error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/server.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My folder structure is like this
frontend
-php
-- server.php
-src
--components
--elements
--pages
---testing.js
--app.js

server.php

```
<?php
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    $user = $_POST['name'];
    echo ("Hello from server: $user");
?>
```

testing.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";

  
function Testing() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [result, setResult] = useState("");
  
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
    };
  
    const handleSumbit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Fire");
        const form = $(e.target);
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            mode: 'no-cors',
            crossDomain : true,
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success(data) {
              console.log("succuess");
                setResult(data);
            },
        });
    };
  
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form
                action="http://localhost:8000/server.php"
                method="post"
                onSubmit={(event) => handleSumbit(event)}
            >
                <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                />
                <br />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <h1>{result}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
  
export default Testing;
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './elements/Navbar/index';
import Footer from './elements/footer';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppContainer }  from "./styles";
import Home from './pages';
import About from './pages/about';
import Contact from './pages/contact';
import Testing from './pages/testing';
//import Exhibitions from './components/Exhibitions';
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <AppContainer>
      <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />    
          <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>} />         
          <Route path='/testing' element={<Testing/>} /> 
      </Routes>
      </AppContainer>
      <Footer />
      </Router>
  );
  }
    
  export default App;
```

can anyone help identify the issue here please, I read some other stack overflow threads where people had a similar issue, however when I tried the answers, none of the fixes worked for me.

I added to the server.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

to the ajax request I added

```
mode: 'no-cors',
crossDomain : true,
```

I also tried the following in my server.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/');
```

and

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: Are you POSTing to the same origin port? You have ports 8000 & 3000 - does you ajax request account for this?

Comment: My php folder is running on port 8000 and the frontend of the site is on 3000.
My from action in testing.js is action="http://localhost:8000/server.php"

Comment: You cannot use `mode: 'no-cors'` if your client is to access the response.

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/');` won't work because a Web origin doesn't contain a path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75386507/can-a-script-loaded-from-example-com-script-js-make-fetch-request-to-example-co/75386704#75386704

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 127.0.0.1');` won't work either because `127.0.0.1` is not valid Web origin (it lacks a scheme and `://`) and also because your request's origin is `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: Finally, be aware that the wildcard (`*`) cannot be used in conjunction with credentialed requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards